# CreateMutex never returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am using [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to stop multiple application to run certain functions at the same time. These functions are in dll so can be called over by same application or separate applictions. This dll talks to hardware so I want to return 'busy' if another function is already running rather than have to wait on it. I thought best approach is to use CreateMutex instead combination of OpenMutex.

```
int FunctionExposedByDll()
{

    hMutexAPI = CreateMutex(0, 0, API_RUNNING_MUTEXT );

    if (!hMutexAPI )
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

        if (dwErr == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
            return MY_ERROR_BUSY;
    }

    // actual function here

    CloseHandle( hMutexAPI );

}
```

So if the mutex is already created, I should get `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` which tells me system is executing an api and I should return. However the above code always return a valid mutex even if the prior function has not returned and mutex handle is not closed.

I also tried `CreateMutexEx` function and in that case when I try it the 2nd time it returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when I am expecting ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. So my question is what do I need to do to get correct status that mutex already exist when it exist?

I am using windows 7

****Update****

Based on Rob K answer, I have changed the code to following:

```
int FunctionExposedByDll()
{

    hMutexAPI = CreateMutex(0, 0, API_RUNNING_MUTEXT );


    DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

    if (dwErr == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
    {
        CloseHandle( hMutexAPI); // i have to call this but it contributes to first chance exception too!
        return MY_ERROR_BUSY;
    }

    // actual function here

    CloseHandle( hMutexAPI );

}
```

Now I am getting/reading the correct status of semaphore but releasing is an issue. If I don't release it when its in 'busy state', than I always get the ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS even when the other API has finished. So CloseHandle() fixes that but creates another issue. When I return and close `CloseHandle()`from busy state and the first API completes later and want to close the handle, I get first chance exception. I don't see how can I avoid that!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the correct way to use `CreateMutex()`. `CreateMutex()` (almost) always succeeds in returning a valid handle to a mutex. From the MSDN doc which you linked: "If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the **return value is a handle to the existing object**, GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS..."

Quoting again: "Two or more processes can call CreateMutex to create the same named mutex. The first process actually creates the mutex, and subsequent processes with sufficient access rights **simply open a handle to the existing mutex**. This enables multiple processes to get handles of the same mutex, while relieving the user of the responsibility of ensuring that the creating process is started first."

What you want to do is use `CreateMutex()` to open a handle to the mutex, and then use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) with a timeout value of 0 to try to take it. If the `WaitForSingleObject()` fails to take the mutex, then you return MY_ERROR_BUSY.  If it does succeed to take the mutex, call [`ReleaseMutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066.aspx) when you are done using it to unlock it.

**ETA:**

If WaitForSingleObject returns WAIT_OBJECT_0 or WAIT_ABANDONED, then you own the mutex (e.g. it becomes signalled) and you must call ReleaseMutex to give-up ownership (e.g. unsignal it) before calling CloseHandle.

If it returns WAIT_TIMEOUT, you do not own the mutex, and you can just call CloseHandle.

```
int FunctionExposedByDll()
{

    HANDLE hMutexAPI = CreateMutex(0, 0, API_RUNNING_MUTEXT );

    int rval = MY_ERROR_BUSY;    
    if ( hMutexAPI )
    {
        DWORD wait_success = WaitForSingleObject( hMutexAPI, 0 );
        if ( wait_success == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || wait_success == WAIT_ABANDONED )
        {


            // actual function here

            ReleaseMutex( hMutexAPI );
            rval = SUCCESS_VALUE;
        } 
        CloseHandle( hMutexAPI );
    }
    return rval;
}
```

You should take some time to get more familiar with the basic interprocess communication primitives, starting here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex

**ETA once more** 
I figured C++ 11 may have added the IPC primitives to the standard library, and it appears they have:

```
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex, 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard
```

If you're using a C++11 capable compiler (e.g. Visual Studio 2013), please use these instead of the system primitives.

**And one more edit...**
As pointed out in a comment, the C++ standard library primitives are not usable for interprocess communication, only for synchronizing threads in the same process. (This is a great disappointment.)

Instead, use [Boost.Interprocess](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-synchronization) if you can.

Comment: Thanks I get how it is used now but I don't think I need `WaitForSingleObject` with 0 timeout partly because I will always have a valid handle. I should be simply calling GetLastError() and that should be enough, let me try that.

Comment: No, just because it exists doesn't mean it's in use. Process A may have already called `ReleaseMutex()` when its time slice ends before it can call `CloseHandle()`. Then process B calls `CreateMutex()`. Then you have a situation where process A is done with it, but process B can't use it.

You can't use the existence of the mutex as a mutex. Use it properly.

Comment: I have used `WaitForSingleObject` with 0 timeout with event to see if it is signaled or not but I don't know what it means with mutex, it does't have `SetEvent` or `ResetEvent` to change its state!? I am confused!. Should I be calling ReleaseMutex AND CloseHandle? I thought just the later was enough.

Comment: Just checking for ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS is working for me but I have one problem. It appears like I have to call `CloseHandle`when I open the mutex for 2nd time when its in busy state. Failure to do so, it always shows ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS even when the first call has finished and released mutex. But when I `CloseHandle` the mutex in 2nd time and the first function finally completes and want to close handle, I get first chance exception. If I can remove that, I would have my solution but I don't see how to remove that.

Comment: What you are supposed to do is have each app call `CreateMutex()` with the same mutex name **one time** (preferably at startup), and `CloseHandle()` **one time** (preferably at shutdown).  Each app can then call `WaitForSingleObject()` when it wants to acquire the mutex lock before entering the DLL. If `WFSO` is successful, call the DLL as needed, then call `ReleaseMutex()` to release the lock, and then return the desired result to the caller. If `WFSO` fails, return "Busy" if it failed due to `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, otherwise return "Error" instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want the mutex to be internal to dll and don't want third parties to worry about it. It should return busy if any APIs are currently running. I have also updated post.

Comment: I expanded my answer to more fully show what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks @RobK I tried the `WaitForSingleObject`and that approach works perfectly! In my code I am not even calling `ReleaseMutex` and `CloseHandle` alone is enough. Please let me know if there is reason I do have to call `ReleaseMutex` Thank you!

Comment: You can create the mutex when the DLL is loaded, and then close it when the DLL is unloaded. DO NOT use `CloseHandle()` to release a mutex lock that you have obtained with `WaitForSingleObject()`, you MUST use `ReleaseMutex()` instead. DO NOT repeatedly open and close the mutex, that defeats the purpose of using a mutex for synchronization.

Comment: You should keep a handle to the mutex for the lifetime of your program's interest in using the protected resource. If your program will call FunctionExposedByDll() more than once, you should have the handle created and closed outside of FunctionExposedByDll(), when you load and unload the DLL. And you really MUST call ReleaseMutex(). Otherwise it takes the OS a lot longer to mark it as unsignaled. Do it correctly now, and you won't be angry with yourself later when you're having problems from not doing it correctly.

Comment: You might also consider wrapping the mutex in a class which calls CreateMutex() in the constructor and CloseHandle() in the destructor, and has take() and release() member functions, and also a sentry class which takes a reference to the mutex class as argument to its constructor and calls take() on that mutex, and then calls release() in its destructor. That's the thread-safe RAII way of handling mutexes. It's actually very quick to write.

Comment: Thanks @RobK I have already created AutoRelease class which releases mutex in destructor however I discovered a problem. This code works in same application but when I run two instances of my application, they don't wait on the same mutex! Any ideas? Thx

Comment: Are you still using the named mutex?

Comment: @RobK Sorry it was false alarm, it appeared like so because of another issue.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the source of the confusion was. 1) The misleading thought that `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` from `GetLastError()` means there is already an active program owning the resource. 2) The misleading thought that `CloseHandle` is the way to yield or give up the resource. 3) The misleading thought that after a successful `WaitForSingleObject`, then it must be followed by a call to `CloseHandle` to yield or give up the resource. These confusing points, once clarified should be able to help one understand better `mutual exclusion` primitive in Windows API. Thanks.

Comment: The most recent edit on this answer is incorrect. C++11 does not have any interprocess primitives. std::mutex is for thread synchronisation, not process synchronisation.

Comment: @PeterBloomfield, sadly, you appear to be correct. I jumped to conclusions. There doesn't seem to be a way to create a named mutex, which would be required for IPC. This is disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateMutex` returns a valid handle anyway. That is, a test for `!hMutexAPI` fails and you never enter the clause.