# OK or unsafe way to use winapi CreateMutex

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex

I found a piece of code where the mutex implementation looks like below. It is used to protect from multiple instances of the application accessing the same code. I do understand that it is the wrong way of using mutex. This is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547947/createmutex-never-returns-error-already-exists) where a correct way to use the mutex can also be seen. However what I want to know is if this is an unsafe mutex implementation. It is not likely to be changed if it is actually safe so I need some arguments if I want it changed.

```
int GetNamedMutex(LPCTSTR mutexName, HANDLE& hMutex)
{    
    if (!hMutex)
    {
        hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, mutexName);

        if (!hMutex)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            // is already in critical state.
            CloseHandle(hMutex);
            hMutex = NULL;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void DestroyMutex(HANDLE& hMutex)
{
    if (hMutex)
    {
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        CloseHandle(hMutex);
        hMutex = NULL;
    }
}

int ExampleFunction()
{
   HANDLE myMutex = NULL;
   GetNamedMutex("myMutexName", myMutex);
   if (myMutex)
   {
      //Run critical code
      //...

      DestroyMutex(myMutex);
   }
}
```

Comment: First, you're not implementing a mutex, you're using one (sort of). Secondly, if the caller of this *thing* never checks the result of the function, it seems pretty pointless. Third, you pass an indeterminate value for the uninitialized local `myMutex` from `ExampleFunction`, so the very check of `if(!hMutex)` invokes undefined behavior. Fourth, this appears to protect nothing, and unlocks a mutex that you don't even own (was never latched). In short, this makes little to no sense *at all*, and it is completely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: The ExampleFunction (edited some minutes ago) is checking if it gets the HANDLE to the mutex. If the handle is already taken by someone else it wont get the handle. (I know it is not actually using the mutex, just the handels to mutexes)

Comment: Let me say that differently. `ExampleFunction` has a local var called `myMutex`, the initial value of which is completely indeterminate. It is **uninitialized**. You then pass that into a function by-reference, whereby you specifically checks it against NULL. As you're comparing *indeterminate* data, you're invoking **undefined behavior**. If there is a simpler way to put it than that, I can't think of it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. It should have been initialized to NULL.

Comment: Well, that latest morph fixes *one* of the issues I mentioned. The others are still valid. Please, in the future, post **real** code. it is a waste of time to have people pour over code that is changing like the wind blows.

Comment: Maybe you could write why you think this to be unsafe. As it is now it seems to work like a lock file, I don't see why it would be unsafe.

Comment: I thought of it to be unsafe since it isn't actually using the mutex but just the handle and ReleaseMutex always gives error "Attempt to release mutex not owned by caller". But as you say, it might be safe anyway and works as a lock file. The tests I have tried seems to work fine.

Comment: This pattern didn't start out as a way to synchronize a process' threads -- it was originally a way to prevent multiple instances of the same executable from running at the same time.  It uses a named mutex so it can be found and accessed by multiple, separate processes, and the name is chosen to be unique to that application.  At startup, the app attempts to create the mutex, and if it already exists, it knows another instance is already running, so it exits.  This mutex doesn't even get locked -- synchronization relies on the mechanisms behind creation of kernel objects by the OS.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct. Is it unsafe to do it this way or is it just a bad implementation? A lot of callings to GetNamedMutex could result in several opening and closing of handles. Could that be unsafe?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles: What you describe may be the predominant use case for this scheme. It is, however, more general than that, and both this question as well as the question linked to use a mutex to prevent a piece of code to run at the same time from different instances of an application (or library). This is the generic use case, and it is perfectly fine as implemented in this question. Besides, the mutex **does** get locked by the first caller to `CreateMutex`, so subsequent callers get an error, until `ReleaseMutex` is invoked by the owner.

Comment: I doubt this code would ever pass a security review.  It suffers from a simplistic DOS attack issue, all an attacker has to do is create its own *mutexName* and your program can never run again.  How much of a problem that really is tends to depend heavily on how successful you plan to be.  These kind of loopholes tend to be patched-up later, if found.

Comment: @HansPassant. Isn't that always a problem with named mutex even if I lock it correctly? I guess a hacker can create something like a semaphore with the same name so that my mutex cannot be created from the start.

Comment: No, you'd expect a decent diagnostic from a program that needs to create a mutex and it is *not* expected to fail.

Comment: @HansPassant: Your proposed security risk requires, that you are already past the airtight hatchway. When you are in a position to create a named mutex that can cause an application to fail to run, you can do far worse. You do not want to run into an accidental DOS attack, by picking a generic mutex name. The solution to this is to pick a unique name (e.g. string representation of a GUID).

Comment: You are overlooking the "legitimate" reasons for a DOS attack.  Like a competitor's program that wants to steal your business.

Comment: @IInspectable I only see one `CreateMutex` call in OP's code and Initial Owner parameter is `FALSE`.  But it doesn't need to be locked anyway, because ownership is determined by who wins the race to create the object first.  And this "mutex" has strange semantics - it can't block a thread, it can only fail to be acquired.  That's fine for an application that uses the mutex to find out if another instance exists, because it's just going to exit on failure to aquire.  I don't doubt that the code could be used for thread synchro - if it is, its an obvious bastardization of the original intent.

Comment: @HansPassant: Now that is ludicrous. If a competitor wants to steal your business, that competitor will steal your business. In case they break your application it won't be a secret for long, that your competitor is playing an unfair game. I guess your standard advice to this competitor would be: *"Make sure your uninstaller is well tested. It will get executed a lot."*